# Create own Git repo with bare option

Tags: git

I am new to git, Just i want move my project work to Git for version control. Before moving/using Git I am doing testing.

```
 Note: we are not using Public/Private github. We are using own git reposity server.
```

I have shared directory "/share"

I have created bare repostory like below:

```
 git init --bare /share/centralproject.git
```

I have created local repo:

```
 cd /share/local
 #create two files hello.py and README.md
 git init
```

Locally I have staged and commited like below:

```
 git add .
 git commit -m "Commit 1"
```

Added remote repo like below:

```
 git remote add myremoterepo file:///share/centralproject.git 
 git push myremoterepo master
```

I did not see any of my files (local repo files hello.py and README.md) in remote repository that is under "/share/centralproject.git"

what i am trying to achieve here is all my codes must reside in central directory in my case "/share/centralproject.git".

We have 10 developer, These developers are going to check in there codes from local repo to remote repository in my case again "/share/centralproject.git"

Comment: Please learn the difference. **git /= github**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly normal: a bare repository is a repository without a working directory. You can see that your commit is there by using `git log` inside your bare repository, but it won't checkout files anywhere.

Comment: Got It, I get those files from remote repository by cloning. Just I have cloned remote resposity I am able see the files..

Comment: @meteor23 well, congrats for your first Git server setup then :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have conflated the client and server functionality. Both can be performed by one computer. The discussion of the `file` protocol below addresses this issue.

Do the procedure again, but this time do not create a bare repo. Simply type:

```
git init
```

The instructions for creating a new repo on the git server varies according to the server. Please refer to the documentation for your server.

I recommend you use `localhost`, or any other IP address, instead of the `file` protocol. [From the manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols):

> Git operates slightly differently if you explicitly specify file:// at
>   the beginning of the URL. If you just specify the path, Git tries to
>   use hardlinks or directly copy the files it needs. If you specify
>   file://, Git fires up the processes that it normally uses to transfer
>   data over a network, which is generally much less efficient. The main
>   reason to specify the file:// prefix is if you want a clean copy of
>   the repository with extraneous references or objects left
>   out — generally after an import from another VCS or something similar
>   (see Git Internals for maintenance tasks). We’ll use the normal path
>   here because doing so is almost always faster.

Comment: are you telling me to use ssh protocol in this case?

Comment: The protocols supported depend on the git server. If the `git` protocol is supported, use it. Next best is `ssh`. Next best is `http`.

Comment: Ok Let me try the git protocol and other permissions options. Thanks